# Password Reset Strategy?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to figure out a password reset strategy for user's on localhost only without the need to send it to an actual email over the internet. This is for a school project and no access to the internet is allowed. I have searched everywhere and could only find tutorials and guides about resetting passwords by sending it the user's email addresses.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please of how to achieve such a task!

Comment: how about asking a secret question, that only the user knows the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Security Question (with Captcha if you want to be safer). If users want to reset his/her password he/she must answered security question right. Another way users have to ask to System Administrator, fill some form, and show student card or something.

Comment: Security question? Does that mean I have to add an extra field to the user's database table and give another input for the registration form?

Comment: For simplicity yes. But you can also create another table that filled with security question and the answer. But it will be more complicated.

Comment: ok thanks, I will go with the simplicity because I am new to web coding.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the user for the first time, you could ask them a couple of secret security questions (like "what is your mother's middle name?"), and use those for account verifications. Hope this helps!

Comment: ok thanx, I will try to find something about this!

Comment: please don't forget to upvote this and mark this as answered if this works for you.